# What is a "provisional transcript, stating your provisional grades"?

Tags: grades, transcript-of-records

I am set to do a masters degree in the UK starting in mid September this year. It is exactly one year long. 
I intend to do another masters after it which begins in October next year.
The structure of the course is we are examined on 4 modules in January and examined on 4 modules in June. We then write our dissertation from June to September. The weighting of the dissertation is 4 modules. 
My problem is that I will have all my modules marks by September but not the dissertation mark. 
I will get my certificate around November time.

I emailed the course director and he said that

"as long as you can get a provisional transcript, stating your provisional grades, before September, you are fine for the programme".

Does this mean that even if I do not get all my marks back before September, I am still eligible to apply and be accepted on the course?

Does provisional transcript mean an unofficial transcript with all my grades?
Or does it mean a transcript with my grades so far?

Answer (score 3):

Provisional transcript: The school's current best indication of your classes and grades, subject to correction if necessary.

Comment: Ok, so if I get a conditional offer for my second masters, they wont know if I have met the terms because my final grade will be published after the start date of the new course because of my dissertation.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So then I will have to take a year out? Or do they only care about my module marks and only use them to work out if I will meet the offer? Is that not a big risk though as someone may completely fail the dissertation?

Comment: They understand that risk. They're doing initial screening now and may make you a provisional offer,  conditional upon your finishing.

Comment: oh ok. I think I understand. I will apply after my first semester results so basically the offer will be based on my potential?

Answer (score 0):

Ask around at your current school to find out what kind of official transcript you can get for what you have already completed, and then forward that asking if it is enough (with a list of the courses you are currently attending, and your immediate plans on other courses). If not enough, they might ask for further details, like partial grades and an explanation of grading system in your courses, but there you'll have to provide what they require.

Comment: Provisional transcripts usually include an explanation of the grading system.

Comment: @JoErNanO, I meant more in the line of "midterm grade is so and so, which is this part of the grade"